# android prevent EditText from requesting focus automatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a quite simple Layout with an EditText and a button. The problem is the keyboard appears immediately after the activity is started and the EditText gets the focus. I removed the `</requestFocus>` from XML and I also don't do that in code. How can I prevent that behavior of EditText so the keyboard only appears after the used taps the editText?

Comment: Are you sure you removed all requestFocus? It shouldn't open your keyboard if you don't request it anywhere. Maybe posting your code could help.

Comment: do you still have any issue regarding it ??

Comment: Adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on my **parent layout** works for me.

Answer (score 5):

In your `manifest.xml` file, under the activity tag, place this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue. Can you tell me if that code can have any side effects which I should keep in mind?

Comment: The answer below using `adjustNothing` is better. If you use `stateHidden`, then the keyboard will be closed when open on rotate. That is not usually desirable behavior.

Comment: I cannot believe how many people state this very wrong answer.

Answer (score 4):

try this

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file write these lines

```
<activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

i just added details..

Answer (score 3):

From my POV a more elegant solution is:

1. In XML add these lines to the main layout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       ...
       .../>
   ```
2. And In Java in onCreate():

   ```
     LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
     mainLayout.requestFocus();
   ```